# Send me mail on rsnapshot fail

Tags: email, rsnapshot

I am using rsnapshot for daily/weekly backups which are triggered by anacron, that works nice.

However instead of checking the logs by hand, I would like to receive a mail whenever a backup failed. This mail should consist of the full rsnapshot output.

I did not find this feature in the rsnapshot.conf or man-page, so I quess I have to script it myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did for now:
First I installed "postfix" as mail-server. Than I added some lines to my shell-script:

```
...
OUTPUT=`rsnapshot $ARGUMENT`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo "${OUTPUT}" | mail -s "rsnapshot report" myname@gmail.com
fi
```

**Edit:**
Actually it is much more useful to just forward all local mails to my private mail-account.
This can be done by changing just one line in `/etc/aliases`:

```
#root: mylocalaccount <-- comment out old line and add:
root: myname@gmail.com
```

Like that, the output of all cron/anacron-jobs which are marked with "--report" are automatically sent to me.

Comment: Which file did you add this to?